# ошибка запуска приложения spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

я пробую создавать телеграмм бота на основе spring boot. во время запуска вылетает ошибка:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.12.1/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.12.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
```

Пытался вставлять вот так в pom.xml:

```html
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
 <exclusions>
     <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
 </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Но по непонятной мне причине в Project Structure -> Modules -> Language level уровень Java меняется с 8 на 5 и вылетает ошибка. потому что я использую лямбды..

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: поменяйте с 5 на 8.

Comment: это надо сделать не только в Project Structure

Comment: @michael_best я как раз все так и сделал, но idea сама по какой-то причине возвращает настройки к 5 версии